# Cancelled requests reduce network speed

Tags: c#, tcp, httpclient

When I cancel a HTTPClient request, say while stopping debug, the connection seems to hang somewhere and slow down my entire network.  It doesn't seem to occur after one or two times, but doing this multiple times slows down all devices on my network.  The only fix I have found is to reset my router.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content;
        var responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        //stopped debugging here
    }
}
```

How can I find and close these connections manually <s>or programmatically</s>?

Comment: So, it this a sizeable download? The other end is probably still sending the data, unaware that you've hung-up. Implement some sort of cancellation that disposes of everything disposable prior to pulling the plug.

Comment: @spender it is not a particularly large download. I can come up with a programmatical way to do this. I was looking for a manual way as well. _Edited the original post._

Comment: Perhaps if you were to use Fiddler or [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/tcpview) to check if it is actually your machine that is holding the connection. I suspect it's out of your hands at this point, and it's down to your router. Graceful shutdown of your requests is the best way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) helped a lot. Seems like a lot of people have run into this issue and found that booting Fiddler fixes it. It offers a lot of additional info on the problem as well.